# Quality standards are not met

Tags: support, question-quality, quality-filter, rejected-questions

I have written a question that did not meet the standards (see below).

I noticed that just by adding uppercase correctly, it meets the standards.

Is this okay?

[image: Top: not accepted. Bottom: accepted.]

Comment: Please bear in mind that the worst this is meant to prevent is _absolutely terrible, awful, atrocious_ posts. If you can string together a decent sentence and care remotely about things like correct grammar, punctuation and capitalisation, you are probably not the target audience of this quality filter.

Comment: You were able to use capitalization here properly.  Why not in the referenced question?

Comment: @Won't Check the revision history.

Comment: @AstroCB oooh, sick burn.  Ow.

Comment: I would like to communicate with others. I believe I was banned unfairly and it proves to me how unfriendly this site is when I can't even voice my opinion anywhere except where I'm not supposed to put it. I can't even post in help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ...and is written using proper grammar.

Something in the code probably checks for capitalization; you have multiple lowercase `i`s and the first letters of your sentences are not capitalized.

While someone would probably edit your post to fix those things after you submit the question, it's best to fix it before you even put it in front of others' eyes so that people pay attention to the question itself rather than the way it's written.

The question includes an image and three fairly short sentences, which is a red flag when it comes to question quality because it may mean that you haven't entirely described your problem and are using an image as a substitute for explanation.